# Function to find closest number out of array always returns first element of array

Tags: arrays, c

In my program. I need to write a function and input a target number. The function must go through the array of elements and find the closest number to the target number. I managed to find the example functions here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-closest-number-in-array-in-cplusplus

All I did was change to array to

```
int arr[] = { 2970, 2950, 2930, 2910, 2880, 2860, 2840 };
```

Full code :

```
static int getNearest(int x, int y, int target) {
   if (target - x >= y - target)
      return y;
   else
      return x;
}

static int getNearestElement(int arr[], int n, int target) {
   if (target <= arr[0]){
      return arr[0];
   }

   if (target >= arr[n - 1]){
      return arr[n - 1];
   }

   int left = 0, right = n, mid = 0;
   while (left < right) {
      mid = (left + right) / 2;
      if (arr[mid] == target){
         return arr[mid];
      }
      if (target < arr[mid]) {
         if (mid > 0 && target > arr[mid - 1]){
            return getNearest(arr[mid - 1], arr[mid], target);
         }
            right = mid;
      }
       else {
         if (mid < n - 1 && target < arr[mid + 1]){
            return getNearest(arr[mid], arr[mid + 1], target);
         }
         left = mid + 1;
      }
   }
   return arr[mid];
}



int get_temperature(int target){


        int arr[] = { 2970, 2950, 2930, 2910, 2880, 2860, 2840 };
        int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        return (getNearestElement(arr, n, target));



}
```

And in my main.c I call:

```
    int closest_temperature = get_temperature(2900);
    printf("closest temperature = %i\n",closest_temperature);
```

The output is:

```
closest temperature = 2970
```

It seems that it always returns the first element of my array even though the closest number is 2910. Could someone help me spot the error?

Comment: is it guaranteed that `arr` is decreasing?

Comment: `if (target <= arr[0])` This check assumes that the array is sorted in ascending order. This is not the case for your array.

Comment: From your link: "And elements are sorted.". You change the array to violate this constraint and don't update any code to take account for that change. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: it looks that all you need to do is to reverse `arr`

Comment: Ah what a silly mistake. Thank you very much..

Comment: Note that `getNearest` is buggy though. Make that comparison into something like `if(abs(y-target) < abs(x-target))`

Comment: You have a working alternative in my comment above. Consider this if you use your current code: `getNearest(2910, 2907, 2909)`. Which is nearest 2909? That's 2010, right? Not according to your function though. It'll return 2907.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Thank you